# Disable Flash Plugin on chrome when running test with robot framework

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to simulate a test that will playing a video based on vjs player, so I need to disable flash plugin to make it work (the default player is jwplayer). Below is piece of my code (as keywords), which is still not work for me:

```
*** Keywords ***
Open Chrome Without Flash
  [Arguments]         ${url}
  ${options}=         Evaluate                  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()     sys, selenium.webdriver
  ${profile}=         Create Dictionary         plugins.plugins_disabled=Adobe Flash Player
  Call Method         ${options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${profile}
  Create Webdriver    Chrome                    chrome_options=${options}
  Go To               ${url}
```

My environment setup:

- Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116
- Robot Framework 3.0
- Selenium2Library 1.7.4
- Chromedriver 2.23.409687

Perhaps anyone know how to make it work with robot framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit untested for your case but this is what I found on how to disable plugins in my Chrome:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Open Chrome
  Set Options
  Goto  ${SOME_URL}

*** Keywords ***
Set Options
  ${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
  ${disabled}=  Create List  Adobe Flash Player
  ${preferences}=  Create Dictionary  plugins.plugins_disabled=${disabled}
  Call Method  ${options}  add_experimental_option  prefs  ${preferences}
  Create WebDriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${options}
```

You might need to verify the name of the Flash plugin (`Adobe Flash Player` in the above code).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to disable it (using ugly technique as suggested in other StackOverflow answers).

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Test disabling Flash Plugin in Chrome
Library           Selenium2Library    15.0    5.0

*** Test Cases ***
    Open Chrome And Disable Flash    https://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/fmp_player/_jcr_content/articlecontentAdobe/videomodal_0.content.html

*** Keywords ***
Open Chrome And Disable Flash
    [Arguments]    ${url}
    Open Browser    about://plugins    Chrome
    Wait Until Page Contains    Plug-ins
    ${myElement}=    Get Web Element    xpath=//div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div[1]/span[.='Adobe Flash Player']/../../../div[contains(@class,'plugin-actions')]/span/a[contains(@class,'disable-group-link')]
    Click Element    ${myElement}
    Go To    ${url}
```

My environment setup:

- Linux - Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two) x64bit
- Python 2.7.10
- Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116
- Robot Framework 3.0
- Selenium2Library 1.8.0b2
- Selenium 2.53.6
- Chromedriver 2.22.397932

Comment: Ugh... yeah that's a bit ugly, also I usually avoid using xpath, because it's a little hard to read, and some people says it will adding a little more time to execute than regular strategy locator, like sizzle.

Thanks after all, but I will wait for another answer